# How to access static variable from another class?

Tags: java, class, variables, static

I'm trying to access the variable "name" in the Client class from the Server class. This is what I tried to do, but when I print it, it says it's null (?). How can I fix this? Thanks in advance...

Client class

```
class Client {
    static Socket socket;
    static String name;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String hostname = "";
        int port = 0;

        if (args.length == 3) {
            hostname = args[0];
            port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            name = args[2];
            System.out.println("(" + hostname + ":" + port + ")");
        } else {
            hostname = "localhost";
            port = 3000;
            name = "default";
            System.out.println("Using all default arguments. (" + hostname + ":" + port + ")");
        }

        Client c = new Client(hostname, port);
        c.connect();
    }
}
```

Server class

```
class Server {
    ServerSocket main;
    Helper helper;

    static class MailServer extends Thread {
        DataInputStream dataIn;
        DataOutputStream dataOut;
        int index;
        Helper helper;
        String name = Client.name; //<--- HERE
    }
}
```

Comment: Presumably the client and server run in different JVMs... or perhaps I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 1):

If the Client and Server classes are running in the same JVM, then your code should work, assuming that the bits that you haven't shown us are correct.

So ... you are (most likely) launching the `Client` in one JVM and the `Server` in another one.  The `Client.name` statics are different.  When you assign a value in the client JVM, it doesn't magically propagate to the server JVM.